# How to store value to database from a dropdown menu in MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, menu, dropdown

I am learning ASP.NET MVC5 since a couple days, trying to complete a proyect that requires some dropdown menus. I can't, sadly, get over this problem, maybe someone here can give me a clue.

So basically, I am requesting all users to the database and displaying them into a dropdown menu, that works perfectly, but when I save changes on my formular, for some reason all values are stored properly in the database, but not those from the dropdown menus.

Create.cshtml

```
    <div class="form-group">
        @if (ViewBag.Users != null)
        {
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Student, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.DropDownList("Users", "Student")
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Student, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        }
    </div>
----------------------

<div class="form-group">
    @if (ViewBag.Users != null)
    {
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Teacher, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
        @Html.DropDownList("Users", "Teacher")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Teacher, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    }
</div>
```

---

ClassesControler.cs

```
// GET: Classes/Create
        Entities2 database = new Entities2();

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        List<AspNetUsers> Users = database.AspNetUsers.ToList();
        ViewBag.Users = new SelectList(Users, "UserName", "UserName");

        return View();
    }

    // POST: Classes/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Id,StudentsReport,TeachersReport,Language,TeachersEarning,Student,Teacher,NumberOfClasses,ClassName")] Class @class)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Classes.Add(@class);
                db.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

        return View(@class);
    }
```

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

You can't set the whole `Users` object. Just set the `UserId` property (foreign key), maybe you'll have to add it to your `Classes` model.

Something like this:

Create.cshtml:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.TeacherId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2"})
@Html.DropDownList("TeacherId", null, "Please select", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.TeacherId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
```

Controller.cs

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ...
    ViewBag.TeacherId = new SelectList(db.Users, "TeacherId", "TeacherName");
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = ...,TeacherId,...")] Class class)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Sadly I have no idea about how to implement that. Would you show me some code ? I've been playing with mine for a bit but still cant find the solution.

Comment: Edited the original answer.